# Single-page list of ratings editing, sharing, comparing client-side

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have questions about the best way to implement something. This involves CSS, HTML and Javascript.

My intent is to write something like a list of preferences (How much you like drama from 1-5, romance from 1-5, action 1-5) that's editable client-side, shareable client-side, and comparable client-side (add "thriller"; show off your ratings; compare someone else's ratings with yours). I'd ideally like all of this to take place on a single page.

My interpretation of how to handle the list itself has been through radio buttons and labels. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

My interpretation of how to do the self-editable part is to have a text field on the page with a button that updates the page based on the text inside the field.

However, before I get too deep I want to make sure I'm not approaching this all wrong, and I'd appreciate input on how to do the next bits. Specifically: how should I implement sharing and comparing lists? My instinct was to follow through on my forms but anything with GET will lead to one mess of a url and anything with POST, as far as I know, won't be accessible in the way I want it.

If you can shed some light on this problem, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: can you elaborate more about your implementation, as far as I can understand you have some values which you want to show according to ratings like 1-5 and it should be editable client side like imdb star rating etc and do you want these to update as well in DB?

Comment: That's correct. I don't need an actual db so much as I need a pseudo-one, or a way for the page to read it.
Here's the full, bulky code.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggaVez

Comment: yeah man looking fine only.. as no need to interact with db so you can just manage state in javascript list only that will be good enough.